# Compile time error.When i ran my android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had this error when running app in Android Studio, complile is pass. I can't understand why this error appears. And I found nothing in Internet for the similar error when using card.io. perhaps this is particular for my project due to different dependencies I used.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible because more than one file found for the same resource during compile time.

Try adding this to the `build.gradle` file for the app

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
```

Comment: I have used your answer.it is working perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Would be great if you mark it as an answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by incompatible types in your card,io you have to find that source and update it or there is also a work around for this. 
Enter these lines in your gradle file and then try it should work fine,

> packagingOptions {
>       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'   }